# String is not a valid type fxml

Tags: javafx, combobox, fxml, fxmlloader

I am writting this code of a car store for my school project. In this FXML file, I am receiving an error. In the screen I am writting the user can add a car. So it has an option to select if the car is Hatch, Sedan or SUV. I am trying it with a ComboBox but I keep receiving the same message saying String type insn´t valid.

fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.util.*?>


<VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
fx:controller="com.example.javafxproject.CadastrarNovosCarros">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
        <Label text="Cadastar novos carros" />
    </VBox>

    <HBox spacing="20.0"> 
        <VBox>
            <Label text="Cidade" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfCidade" />

            <Label text="Estado" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfEstado" />

            <Label text="Placa" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfPlaca" />

            <Label text="Ano" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfAno" />

            <Label text="Fabricante" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfFabricante" />
        </VBox>

        <VBox>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
                <Label text="Insira a categoria:" />
            </VBox>

            <ComboBox fx:id="cboModelo" prefWidth="150.0">
                <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <String fx:value="Sedan" />
                        <String fx:value="Hatch" />
                        <String fx:value="SUV" />
                    </FXCollections>
                </items>
            </ComboBox>
            
            <!-- <CheckBox text="Sedan" fx:id="ckbSedan" />
            <CheckBox text="Hatch" fx:id="ckbHatch" />
            <CheckBox text="Suv" fx:id="ckbSuv" /> -->

            <Label text="Marca" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfMarca" />

            <Label text="Modelo" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfModelo" />
            
            <Label text="Cor" />
            <TextField fx:id="txfCor" />

            <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
                <Label text="Insira a direção:" />
            </VBox>

            <CheckBox text="Automático" fx:id="ckbAutomatico" />
            <CheckBox text="Manual" fx:id="ckbManual" />
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
    
    <VBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" spacing="20.0">
        <Button text="Concluir" onAction="#onActionCadastrarcarronovo" />
    </VBox>

</VBox>
```

The error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: String is not a valid type.
/home/troarmen/latorre/javafx-project/target/classes/com/example/javafxproject/cadastros-novos-carros.fxml:46

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2710)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2912)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2842)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2641)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2555)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2523)
        at com.example.javafxproject/com.example.javafxproject.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:14)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:290)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.javafxproject.HelloApplication
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:301)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:157)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
```

Comment: In FXML, you need an explicit `import` for `String`